# Python regex get URL from string

Tags: python, regex

I'm using regular expressions to get a URL from a string

Here is my code:

```
import re

class ProcessWebsite(object):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "Test"

    def set_orden(self, command):
        self.command = command
        return self.getURL()

    def getURL(self):
        regex = re.compile("([0-9A-Za-z]{2,}\.[0-9A-Za-z]{2,3}\.[0-9A-Za-z]{2,3}|[0-9A-Za-z]{2,}\.[0-9A-Za-z]{2,3})$")
        return regex.findall(str(self.command))
```

I call the method "getURL" from here:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import Tkinter as tk
import tkFont
from Tkinter import StringVar
from Tkinter import Label
from processor.processwebsite import ProcessWebsite



def changeText(newText):
    var.set(newText)

def on_return_release(event):
    pr = ProcessWebsite()
    changeText(pr.set_orden(text.get("1.0", "end")))



app = tk.Tk()

var = StringVar()
label = Label(app, textvariable=var) 
font = tkFont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=36, weight='bold')
label.pack()

text = tk.Text(app, width=50, font=font)
text.config(width=35, height=2)
text.pack()
text.bind("<KeyRelease-Return>", on_return_release)

app.mainloop()
```

This returns me "None", but if I change this line of the method "getURL" then it works

```
def getURL(self):
        regex = re.compile("([0-9A-Za-z]{2,}\.[0-9A-Za-z]{2,3}\.[0-9A-Za-z]{2,3}|[0-9A-Za-z]{2,}\.[0-9A-Za-z]{2,3})$")
        return regex.findall("Test with google.com")
```

Does anyone know what could be happening?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what it is supposed to do? What output should I test with and what should be the output?

Comment: It would appear that `text.get("1.0", "end")` is not returning what you expect it to.  Can you confirm that this produces the desired output?

Comment: I want the domain output "google.com" in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would seem that the text selection doesn't work with `.get(1.0, 'end')`, which is probably due to the newline that was added before you read it.

I don't do Python much and maybe there's a much better approach, but this worked okay:

```
text.get('1.0', 'end -1 chars')
```

Or, to only get the text on the first line:

```
text.get('1.0', '1.end')
```